# Echo result of command preserving echo

Tags: bash

I have a code

```
#!/bin/bash
case "$*" in
  "info" ) echo "INFO * * *";;
  "copy" ) echo `$0 info`;;
esac
```

that prints this

```
$ ./print.sh info
INFO * * *
$ ./print.sh copy
INFO print.sh print.sh print.sh
```

how do I make it to print

```
$ ./print.sh info
INFO * * *
$ ./print.sh copy
INFO * * *
```

preserving `echo` in the copy case:

```
  "copy" ) echo ???;;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quote the backticks so that the asterisks that are substituted in aren't subsequently interpreted as globs and expanded. `$0` should also be quoted for safe measure.

```
"copy" ) echo "`"$0" info`";;
```

Also it's better to use `$(...)` in place of `` `...` `` these days. And no need to quote "info" or "copy".

```
copy) echo "$("$0" info)";;
```

Note that `echo "$(cmd)"` is redundant. You can just call the command directly and skip the `$(...)` and `echo`.

```
copy) "$0" info;;
```